# Read the whole (and not more than the) request body

Tags: python, http, httprequest, wsgi

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

def app(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    return repr(environ['wsgi.input'].readlines()),

make_server('127.63.31.15', 54321, app).serve_forever()
```

When I start this script and try to connect via cURL like this:

```
curl -LvA Mozilla/4.0 -d lol=cat $'http://127.63.31.15:54321/'
*   Trying 127.63.31.15...
* Connected to 127.63.31.15 (127.63.31.15) port 54321 (#0)
> POST / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.63.31.15:54321
> User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 7
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 7 out of 7 bytes
```

... it just hangs. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The reason may be because you are using Python 2.6. Older wsgiref WSGI server had issues which were fixed sometime in Python 2.7 related to reading of request content. Consider using a better WSGI server, or upgrade to latest Python 2.7.

Comment: Upgrading to 2.7 doesn't help. Can you suggest an alternative WSGI server?

Comment: How sophisticated is your application going to be? Why not just use a micro framework which will ensure this sort of stuff is done right and will work. BTW, using a trailing comma like that to create a tuple is not good practice and is obscure.

Comment: My IDE suggested to "Remove redundant parentheses".

Comment: You should have used ``[repr(environ['wsgi.input'].readlines())]``. So not parentheses but square brackets.

Comment: There aren't any advantages in having a mutable iterable here.

Comment: The issue is readability. Many people wouldn't see the trailing comma, nor understand that having it there will actually cause the item to be turned into a single value tuple. Look through tutorials on WSGI and you will generally always see a list of strings is being returned rather than a tuple.